# PHP Unit Skeleton Generator not working

Tags: phpunit

I am trying to install [PhpUnit skeleton generator](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-skeleton-generator). I am also using PhpStorm 5.0.

I get the feeling that it does not install itself properly because when I try to run the skeleton generator it gives me an error saying:

```
'phpunit-skelgen.bat' not found at...
```

Also, it seems that pear does install it in my `pear` folder under the `SebastianBergmann\PHPUnit\SkeletonGenerator` folder, which seems odd since I would have expected it in the main `pear` folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

That's because the phpunit-skelgen.bat file is actually installed in the php folder, not in pear. So just search for it in the root of the php installation folder.

Comment: Can be installed there, now always though